# How proof this property in a Hilbert space of infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I have problems with this proof,

$$u_{1},u_{2},...$$ this is an orthogonal set of vectors in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Show if

$$x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty  c_{j}u_{j}$$

so...
$$\|x\|^2 =\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lvert c_{j} \right\rvert^2 $$

thx guys

Comment: You're right I wrote wrong, sorry my english isn`t good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\|x\|^2 = \langle x, x \rangle = \left\langle\sum_i c_i u_i, \sum_j c_j u_j \right \rangle
= \sum_i \sum_j c_i \overline{c_j} \langle u_i, u_j \rangle.$$
Then use the fact that $u_1,u_2,\ldots$ is orthonormal. (Orthogonality is not enough.)